# Making a shapefile editor with in geotools jmappane

Tags: java, gis, geotools

What would be involved in creating a shapefile editor with begin, save and and end editing for points, lines and polygons in jmappane for geotools?

I know how to update, delete and add to shapefiles with geotools with transactions, but I am not sure how I would display the updated data before actually having the data updated via the save option or even how to display your own data in jmappane.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to have some interface to allow loading the data and showing them.
2. Do you mean to visually edit a map representation of the data, some kind of tabular/spreadsheet version of the data or some kind of online query generator? Depending on what you want the options are very different.
3. You will need to have some way to export your results to a format the user can download.

Check out [MapShaper](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly possible, one option for you to study is [UDig](https://github.com/locationtech/udig-platform) which is a full GIS system built using [GeoTools](http://geotools.org). If that is too complex for you then you could look at my [ShapefileViewer](https://github.com/ianturton/ShapefileViewer) which shows how you load and display a shapefile but doesn't include any editing functionality.